# Lebesgue's convergence for $H(u_n)\nabla u_n$ where $H$ is not everywhere defined

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces, proof-verification

Consider the Heaviside function that is undefined in zero, i.e.
$$H(t)=\begin{cases} 1&t>0 \\ 0&t< 0\end{cases}$$
Now consider a sequence of $H^1(\Omega)$-functions $u_n\to u$ in the norm of the sobolev space and $u_n(x) \in [-1,1]$ for a.e. $x\in \Omega$ (bounded domain).
Let $f$ be a smooth testfunction.
Can we say that $$\int_\Omega f\cdot H(u_n) \nabla u_n \to \int_\Omega f \cdot H(u) \nabla u$$

Of course one would try to apply Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem (for a subsequence and a subsequence of that). The issue is that I'm not sure to find an integrable bound. The set were $u$ is zero and consequently $H(u)$ is undefined could have positive measure. However on that set I'm not sure how to find a good bound. On the other hand, if the set where $u$ is zero we find that the gradient is $0$ too and we can bound it on that set by $1$.

Having that said, I would think of estimating $|H(u_n)\nabla u_n|^2\leq |\nabla u_n|^2$. The latter sequence converges in $L^1(\Omega)$ (by assumption). Hence a generalized version of Lebesgues theorem yields that $H(u_n)\nabla u_n \to H(u)\nabla u$ in $L^2$ and consequently we can pass to the limit in the integral.

Is my reasoning correct? Does anyone have an idea on how to attack the problem without the gradient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. But the problem simplifies if $H(u)\nabla u$ is written as $\nabla u^+$, where $u^+=\max(u,0)$. (The equality of these two things is standard: e.g., Proposition 3.22 of Chapter 3 of [*Lecture Notes on PDEs*](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/pdes.html) by Hunter.) The sequence $(u_n^+)$ is bounded in $H^1$, hence has a weakly convergent subsequence $u_{n_k}^+\to v$. On the other hand, for its subsequence we have convergence a.e. to $u^+$. [Hence](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/803344/147263) $v=u^+$.

Comment: The Lemma you need is also known as Stampacchia's Lemma and in the mean time I'm ashamed of having asked the question :)