# If $f_{n}\rightharpoonup \bar{f}$ and $f_{n}(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ pointwise a.e., then is $\bar{f} = f$ a.e.?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Suppose $f_{n}$ is a sequence of functions in $L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^{d})$ such that $\|f_{n}\|_{L^{p}} \leq 1$ for all $n$ and $f_{n}(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ pointwise almost everywhere as $n \rightarrow \infty$. If I also know that $f_{n}$ converges weakly in $L^{p}$ to an $\bar{f}$, then is $\bar{f} = f$ a.e.?

Comment: Hint : Do you know Egorov's Theorem?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803344/pointwise-a-e-convergence-and-weak-convergence-in-lp).

Comment: The boundedness condition is redundant, since weakly convergent sequences are bounded.

Comment: Actually, for $1<p<\infty$, your conditions in the first sentence imply weak convergence of $(f_n)$ to $f$.