# Same limit for a different convergence

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How can you show that if a sequence $(x_n)$ converges in $L^2$ to $X$, and converges almost surely to $Y$, then $X$ and $Y$ are almost surely the same. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: Yes, But I find it really hard for me to finish the prove after triangle inequality.

Comment: Convergence in $L^2$ implies convergence in probability...

Comment: so, convergence in probability means every sub sequence has a further sub sequence that convergence almost surely to X, then what should I do? that's all I have done. Thanks!

Comment: Yes! But this subsequence converges almost surely to $Y$ as well.

Comment: That is where I have problem with, can you give me some more details? Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome! Since $x_n$ converges almost surely to $Y$, any subsequence converges almost surely to $Y$ as well. Tell me if you want more details.

Answer (score 2):

As Daniele A said, the equality $X=Y$ a.s. follows from the  fact that a sequence that converges to $X$ in $L^2$ has a subsequence converging to $X$ a.s. Since the same subsequence converges to $Y$ a.s., the result follows.

---

A more general statement can be found in  [Pointwise a.e. convergence and weak convergence in Lp](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/803344/)