# If $f_n \rightarrow f_1$ a.e. and $f_n \rightarrow f_2$ weakly,then $f_1=f_2$ a.e.

Tags: functional-analysis

It's an exercise 14 of chapter 1 from stein's functional analysis,here the sequence $\{f_n\}$ satisfy $\|f_n\|_{L^p}\leq M<\infty$ and $1<p<\infty$.See $(c)$ part[image: here]

Is $f_1$ and $f_2$ must be in $L^p$?According to the definition in exercise 12 it seems so.[image]Does anyone know how to prove $(c)$ part

Comment: Does Stein really use these strange notations? $f_1$ and $f_2$ have two meanings in part c).

Comment: Please show some effort on your part.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy My effort is if $f_1$ is in $L_p$ (though I'm not sure about it),then $\int (f_1-f_2)g=0$ for all g in $L^q$,I think I should choose a special g but  failed.

Comment: 1) $f_1 \in L^{p}$ is immediate from Fatou's Lemma. 2) Take $g=\chi_A$ where $A is a set of finite measure.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy For part 2) I have thought it before,but failed,now I take $g=(f_1-f_2)\chi_A$ where A is all rational,so $f_1=f_2$ on all rational but not on all $\mathbb R$,and approaching $f_i$ with continuous function seems not work

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/803344/pointwise-a-e-convergence-and-weak-convergence-in-lp).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hints:

1. $~$ If $(u_n)$ is a sequence in a normed space $X$ such that $u_n $ converges weakly to some $u \in X$ then there exists a sequence $(v_n)$ in $X$ with $v_n \in \operatorname{conv} \{ u_1,u_2, \dots \}$ such that $v_n \to u$.
2. If $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$ then there exists a subsequence of $f_n$ that converges a.e. to $f$.

Edit: The proof of 1.  uses [Mazur's theorem](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/mazur-s-theorem). Let $C= \operatorname{conv} \{ u_1,u_2,\dots \}$ (the convex hull of  $(u_n)$). Note that $u \in \overline{C}^w$, the weak closure of $C$, since $u_n \to u$ weakly,  and that   $C$ is convex.  By Mazur's theorem  we have that  $\overline{C} = \overline{C}^w$ and so $x \in \overline{C}$. This then implies the existence of a sequence  $(v_n)$ in $C$ that converges to $u$ in the norm topology.

Comment: what does $v_n \in \operatorname{conv} \{ u_n \colon n \in \mathbb N\}$ mean

Comment: It means that each $v_n$ is a convex combination of the sequence $(u_1, u_2, \dots)$.

Comment: I'v never heard of this term before,and can't prove it,is there some reference

Comment: @math It basically means that each $v_n$ is a (finite) linear combination of $u_1,u_2, \dots$ such that each coefficient of $u_i$ is between 0 and 1, and their sum adds up to $1$.  For instance, $v_3 = (1/3) u_2 + (2/3) u_5$. For a proof of the fact see my edit.

Comment: Well,in the proof,another concept-weak topology exists which is again out of my depths.In 1 part,you say "$v_n \to u$" at last,is the convergence in norm or just usual convergence,since https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazur%27s_lemma say the convergence is in norm.

Comment: $v_n \to u$ means in norm